# Android: custom view's addView() causes null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I've overrided addView(child: View?) in my custom view and inflating layout causes NullPointerException.

My code:

TestView.kt

```
package com.example.testandroid

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import com.example.testandroid.databinding.ViewTestBinding

class TestView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) :
    LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    var binding: ViewTestBinding

    init {
        binding = ViewTestBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
        binding.vTitle.text = "test title 2"
    }

    override fun addView(child: View?) {
        binding.vContainer.addView(child)
    }
}
```

view_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test title"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

FirstFragment.kt

```
package com.example.testandroid

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.testandroid.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass as the default destination in the navigation.
 */
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

fragment_first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <com.example.testandroid.TestView
        android:id="@+id/vTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text 2"/>

    </com.example.testandroid.TestView>
</LinearLayout>
```

NOTE: NullPointerException is thrown even if TestView doesn't have any children in xml.

error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.LinearLayout com.example.testandroid.databinding.ViewTestBinding.vContainer' on a null object reference
```

full stack trace:

```
    Process: com.example.testandroid, PID: 5681
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testandroid/com.example.testandroid.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.example.testandroid:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.testandroid:layout/fragment_first: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.testandroid:layout/fragment_first: Error inflating class com.example.testandroid.TestView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.example.testandroid:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.testandroid:layout/fragment_first: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.testandroid:layout/fragment_first: Error inflating class com.example.testandroid.TestView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.testandroid:layout/fragment_first: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.testandroid:layout/fragment_first: Error inflating class com.example.testandroid.TestView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in com.example.testandroid:layout/fragment_first: Error inflating class com.example.testandroid.TestView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.example.testandroid.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(FragmentFirstBinding.java:54)
        at com.example.testandroid.FirstFragment.onCreateView(FirstFragment.kt:23)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2879)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:394)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
2023-08-09 13:44:26.820 5681-5681/com.example.testandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:227)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1263)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1119)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.example.testandroid.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:50)
        at com.example.testandroid.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:44)
        at com.example.testandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.LinearLayout com.example.testandroid.databinding.ViewTestBinding.vContainer' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testandroid.TestView.addView(TestView.kt:21)
        at com.example.testandroid.databinding.ViewTestBinding.inflate(ViewTestBinding.java:51)
        at com.example.testandroid.TestView.<init>(TestView.kt:16)
            ... 53 more
```

I've tried replacing `binding.vContainer.addView(child)` with `findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.vContainer).addView(child)`, but error is almost the same.
Before migrating to view binding this worked without any issues.

Comment: either you package(com.example.testandroid.TestView) is not correct or its view is not Proper. please check once the View name and Package. Also check binding.vContainer is null or not.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar binding.vContainer is null and that's the point, but i can't figure out why. Why addChild() is called so soon and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the following line

```
binding = ViewTestBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
```

with

```
binding = ViewTestBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, false)
```

avoiding to attach the view to the parent.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. Now error is:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: com.example.testandroid:id/vText1`

Comment: I tried that code and it works

Comment: I checked again and it's working when TestView doesn't have any children added in xml. Please, take a look at fragment_first.xml in question, there TestView has 2 children added: vText1 and vText2. As soon as you add then you'll get `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: com.example.testandroid:id/vText1`.